# youtube reproduction list-like horizontal list jQuery, CSS or Javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking for a plugin or something that help me to emulate the Youtube or Grooveshark reproduction list effect. Someone could help me out and It'd perfect to have an example.

Thanks

An image of what I want: [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a carousel/slider effect in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937471/how-can-i-create-a-carousel-slider-effect-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using JCarousel and modifying the script to slightly to use the youtube embed and add the links underneath. This is not difficult if you know html and css.

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Another way is to write it yourself (if you know javascript or jquery) place one large div with all your slides inside a smaller one, and set the overflow of the smaller outer div to hidden. Then you would move the position of the inner div with javascript on left or right arrow click.

Comment: Your Welcome. How did it work out for you, did that answer your question?

Comment: yep, I planning to make a custom one based on jCarousel